# ShowcaseViews:Показать обучающий экран при первом запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

Подскажите,в какую сторону копать?
это отдельный макет нужно делать или накладывать все на существующем
Необходимо сделать такой вариант:
[image: то что нужно]

Comment: на такой вопрос уже давали недавно ответ, я просто не могу ссылку найти, но тут поискать можно

Comment: @а как искать?)по каким ключевым и словам...

Comment: найти не смог, но дал свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я так и не смог найти ссылку на ответ. Дам свой, начните бурить отсюда: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: может кто нужную ссылку даст,я про тот ответ,что вы говорите)

Comment: может еще кто подскажет?