# Наложить один фон на другой

Tags: java, android, xml

подскажите пожалуйста,необходимо сделать так:
У корневого RelativeLayout я изменил фон, `android:background="@drawable/fragment2"`но этот фон необходимо разместить поверх всей разметки,т.е на передний план, понимаю,что background задаю задний фон,но может можно как-то поверх всей разметки расположить фон.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fragment2">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lldinamik"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/belarus"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/russia"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/japan" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/litva" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/england" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/finland"

            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/france" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_stop"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/button_play"
            android:clickable="true"

            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/play_button" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/sbar"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:max="100"

            android:progress="0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlayer"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=" "
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это должно выглядеть, зачем вам все эти элементы  если они будут закрыты фоном?

Comment: @ newakkoff я просто покажу прозрачный фон с обучение по программе,а потмо его скрою и больше показывать не буду

Comment: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView вот попробуйте библиотеку.

Comment: @newakkoff к моему сожалению,я не нашел толкового совета по ее использовани..а моих знаний пока не хватает

Comment: дело конечно ваше, но я бы рекомендовал скачать проект по ссылке и посмотреть на примере, там ничего сложного.

Comment: @ newakkoff
[link]мне вот такого плана нужно
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528234/showcaseviews%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F[/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `FrameLayout` есть атрибут `android:foreground` в котором собсно и можно задать то что вам нужно:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/fragment2">

    <!-- ваша разметка -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: скажите,а если необходимо показать данный android:foreground="@drawable/fragment2" только один раз и больше не показывать , я делаю так: prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.potehki.potehki.fragments",getCon‌​text().MODE_PRIVATE); if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) { prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit(); frameLayout.setForeground(null); } 

однако,результата нет

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться альфаканалом для элементов которым надо убрать фон. Сделайте для них фон прозрачным.   android:background="@android:color/transparent" . Либо задайте конкретное значение альфаканала  в таком #ARGB или таком формате #AARRGGBB. Где A или АА - значение альфаканала.